# How can I make my fresh MySQL installation under Linux Mint?

Tags: mysql, security, passwords

I've freshly installed MySQL server and client through Mint's package manager. I can log in to MySQL as root, with password. However, when I try to connect to the database as a non-privileged user, "mysql -uroot -p" does prompt for a user, but universally says that access is denied for 'root'@'localhost'.

Something that may or may not be relevant is that I initially tried leaving a specialized installation without a password, then altered the user to set a password. As root, "mysql -u root" worked, and now "mysql -uroot -p" gets me into command line access.

Comment: I don't understand this part of your question: "However, when I try to connect to the database as a non-privileged user, "mysql -uroot -p" does prompt for a user, but universally says that access is denied for 'root'@'localhost'." ---- That command connects with the user "root" and prompts you for a password.

Comment: It prompts me for a password run as root or as unprivileged. If I run "mysql -uroot -p" as root, I am prompted for a password and then get logged in to mysql's command line client. If I do the same as a non-root account, I'm still prompted for a password, but no matter what I give, it tells me access is denied for "'root'@'localhost'".